# jquery event listener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong here,
index.php

```
<div id="divM"></div>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
$("#select01").change(function(){
    var a = $(this).val() + ".php";
    $("#divM").load(a);
});
```

So, a page is loaded inside `divM` and `select03` is inside the loaded page.

index.js

```
$("#select03").on("change", function(){
    alert ("323"); // nothing happens here !
});
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Solved, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$("#divM").on("change", "#select03", function(){
    alert ("323"); // nothing happens here !
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
$(document.body).on("change","#select03", function(){
    alert ("323"); // nothing happens here !
});
$("#select01").change(function(){
var a = $("#select01 option:selected").val() + ".php";
$("#divM").load(a);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to:

```
$(document).on("change", "#select03", function(){
    alert ("323"); // nothing happens here !
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$(document).on("change", "#select03", function(){
    alert ("abc"); // nothing happens here !
});
```